# Change style of pageblock header standard style

Tags: visualforce, css, stylesheets

I want to change some style attributes of pageblock header, like padding-bottom or hight.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply CSS to Pageblock header like following:

.pbHeader {

```
   //put your custom css here
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I would use an outputPanel with assigned style class as a wrapper for the pageBlock, because we can not assign any style classes directly to thr page block. The access a header. The header has a class `mainTitle` or you can just access `H2` tag directly. Don't forget to use `!important` notification:

```
<style>
.panelWrapper .mainTitle {
    background-color: green !important;
    color:white !important;
    padding: 30px 0 20px 40px !important;
}
</style>

<apex:outputPanel styleClass="panelWrapper" layout="block">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Hello">
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Looks like this then:

[image]

Comment: I used this way but the only applied style is color, but the padding didn't change. maybe because I have custom style for panelWrapper. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Neither of the above solutions worked for me. But [this](https://vanityforce.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/customise-colour-of-pageblocksection-header/) did.